# Stripe - is it possible to re-attach a source to a different customer?

Tags: stripe-payments

We'd like to be able to move a card source to a different customer using Stripe API. Is it possible?

Also, is it possible to attach a single card to multiple customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible for security reasons. Once a Source has been attached to a customer it can not be attached to a different one. You can detach the Source which "consumes" it and prevents you from attaching it again.

If multiple customers share the same card you need to create multiple Sources in Stripe and attach each one to a specific customer.

Comment: In our current system we have ability to move orders to a different customer account when we notice the customer used her second email address. After moving the order in our system, we'd like to be able to use the CC data provided with that order, not the CC data associated with the customer to which we moved the order (which might be old for example). That's why we'd like to be able to move the source to the other account in Stripe as well, to keep the data consistent. In fact, after moving the order, we don't need the account initially created. Is there another way to achieve that in Stripe?

Comment: This is not possible no.